# R: How to aggregate data into percentages without missing data for stacked-bar plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, aggregate, stacked-chart

I would like to summarize my "karyotype" molecular data by location and substrate (see sample data below) as percentages in order to create a stack-bar plot in ggplot2.

I have figured out how to use 'dcast' to get a total for each karyotype, but cannot figure out how to get a percent for each of the three karyotypes (i.e. 'BB', 'BD', 'DD').

The data should be in a format to make a stacked bar plot in 'ggplot2'.

Sample Data:

```
library(reshape2)
Karotype.Data <- structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Kampinge", "Kaseberga", "Molle", "Steninge"
), class = "factor"), Substrate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Kampinge", "Kaseberga", "Molle", 
"Steninge"), class = "factor"), Karyotype = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "BB", "BD", "DD"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Location", 
"Substrate", "Karyotype"), row.names = c(135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 
326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L), class = "data.frame")

## Summary count for each karoytype ##
Karyotype.Summary <- dcast(Karotype.Data , Location + Substrate ~ Karyotype, value.var="Karyotype", length)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to do `Karyotype.Summary[,3:5] <- Karyotype.Summary[,3:5]/rowSums(Karyotype.Summary[,3:5])*100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from 'Marat Talipov' and many other answers to questions on Stackoverflow I found out that it is important to load 'plyr' before 'dplyr' and to use 'summarise' rather than 'summarize'. Then removing the missing data was the last step using 'filter'.

```
library(dplyr)
z.counts <- Karotype.Data %>% 
  group_by(Location,Substrate,Karyotype) %>% 
  summarise(freq=n()) 

z.freq <- z.counts %>% filter(Karyotype != '') %>% 
  group_by(Location,Substrate) %>% 
  mutate(freq=freq/sum(freq))
z.freq

library (ggplot2)
ggplot(z.freq, aes(x=Substrate, y=freq, fill=Karyotype)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Location)
```

Now I have created the plot I was looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
z.counts <- Karotype.Data %>% 
  group_by(Location,Substrate,Karyotype) %>% 
  summarize(freq=n()) 

z.freq <- z.counts %>% 
  group_by(Location,Substrate) %>% 
  mutate(freq=freq/sum(freq)*100)
```

Here, the data remain in the long format, so it is straightforward to build the barplot with `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(z.freq) + 
  aes(x=Karyotype,y=freq) + 
  facet_grid(Location~Substrate) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but two issues. I do not want to include the data with missing karyotype data and second, I would like a stacked-bar plot. That said, if I can now figure out how to remove the records with the missing karyotype data, I think I can make the correct plots. Thanks!